# How should an API that calls another API (oauth2) authenticate (grant access to) itself?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

I am about to create an API. The API itself will be calling another oauth2 API.
How should the API authenticate to the other oauth2 API?

When *Website A* makes a call to *API A*, and *API A* makes a call to *API B*, how will *API A* authenticate (i.e click on grant access) when it just is a cURL call from *Website A*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was to change grant type to client_credentials**

```
$accessToken = $this->getProvider()->getAccessToken('client_credentials', [
            'scope' => 'read(all),write(all)'
        ]);
```

After a bit research, I figured out that it is possible to use another **grant type**, *client_credentials*, instead of *authorization_code*. Using client_credentials I wouldn't need to authenticate myself (i.e click on grant access), rather I'd just make an API call which would return the Access Token directly.

In my case where I had gotten my API keys, there was also an option where I had to change type from "Web" to "Service". This then allowed me to get the Access Token with the grant type "client_credentials". Before that I would get an error message in my response when I tried to use the grant type client_credentials.